# FSAudioController music transitions

Tags: ios, audio-player

I'm using `FSAudioController` to play mp3's from my service. I have a URL list and I'm playing songs by shuffling the list.

What I want to do is, 5 seconds before the current song ends, next song will start playing and there will be a soft transition between songs. But I couldn't find anything about how to play 2 songs at the same time.

I thought about using 2 different FSAudioController objects, but I wanted to ask if there is smarter way to do it first.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `FSAudioController` does not support crossfade option so you will have to use 2 different `FSAudioController` objects.